# Why is Sitelinks Searchbox not showing three weeks after adding structured data for it?

Tags: google-search, google-tag-manager, google-sitelinks-searchbox

I dynamically applied this code for WordPress site through Google Tag Manager:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://www.example.com/?s={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

But the expected result not shows yet.

What time it will get to appear or is there anything that I left to execute it?

Comment: How long has it been?

Comment: It's already 3 weeks

Comment: Google is notoriously slow. As well, this may be a feature that is not guaranteed to appear. You may need to wait longer. Much of this may depend upon how quickly Google fetches your home page. Cheers!!

Comment: Sitelinks are only displayed by Google when the algorithm determines that they would be useful to the searcher. If they are not showing, then they determined that they would not be helpful for the searcher.

Comment: I assume that you already have sitelinks showing and you just want to add a search box to your already existing sitelinks.  Correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to add the search box...

Comment: any solution, how to get the visibility of searchbox..